# Orthogonal complement of a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Can somebody explain why the orthogonal complement of a plane is a line? Why is it not another plane perpendicular to the first one?

Comment: In $\mathbb R^3$?  How could a plane be perpendicular to another one?  Any examples?

Comment: @JonasMeyer The plane x=0 is perpendicular to the plane y=0 isn't it?

Comment: @SuzuHirose: The plane $x=0$ is two dimensional; within it, you can go in  a direction perpendicular to the plane $y=0$, or you can go in a direction parallel to the plane $y=0$.  The plane as a whole is not perpendicular to $y=0$.  You would need at least 4 dimensions to have perpendicular 2-dimensional subspaces.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^n$ the orthogonal complement of a subspace $U$ is a (special) subspace which has dimension $n-\dim(U)$. How could they both be two dimensional in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: All points on the line are perpendicular to all points on the plane. In this sense, the line is an orthogonal complement of the points in the plane. The plane is spanned by 2 vectors and the line by 1 so that together they span all of 3D space and you cannot find another subspace orthogonal to the plane. Two planes are not orthogonal subspaces e.g. x = 0 and y = 0. A point on x = 0 is (0, 1, 1) and a point on y = 0 is (1, 0, 1) but their dot product is 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The orthogonal complement satisfies $U\cap U^\perp=\{\vec 0\}$. Two planes, assuming distinct, which pass through the origin will intersect in a line which passes through the origin. So the orthogonal complement cannot be a plane. So it must be either a line or just $\{\vec0\}$. But the normal vector to your plane of course belongs to the orthogonal complement, so it cannot be $\{\vec 0\}$.